# How do I convert an x coordinate to pixels in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, pixel

I have an x coordinate, but I want to convert this to pixels so I can position a text field in a location relative to the screen.

```
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    var xVal = event.clientX;
    var pxVal = xVal.convertToPx();

    div.style.top = pxVal + 'px';
```

Comment: You can use relative units in css. If you want an element to always be 20% from the top, use 20% instead of trying to calculate how many pixels 20% is.

Comment: the `clientX` value is already in pixels relative to the screen.. you can see an example at this pen: https://codepen.io/rhericlya/pen/mKrgEy

Comment: thanks. I didn't clarify this, but I am using a graph library called amcharts and i used a feature where i can add an annotation (w/ a name) to the chart. I was trying to add a feature where if you click on the annotated area, a text box would appear on top of the current name text. I have the x coord of the start and end of the annotation, so I originally positioned the text field at the x coord the center of the annotation. However, I realized that the box started from the center instead of being centered. I got the x val of the txtbox and divided by 2 to find how much to shift box left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `clientX` value is already in pixels relative to the screen. You can see an example in the snippet below:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("div");

x.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = event.clientX + 'px from left';
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-left:0px;
}
#div {
  width:200px;
  height:70px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:70px;
  background:red;
  
}
#feedback {
  position:absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top:130px;
}
ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0px;
}
li {
  border-left:1px solid black;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  padding-left:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>

<div class="ruler">
  <ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>100</li>
    <li>200</li>
    <li>300</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="feedback"></div>
```

---

You can read more about `clientX` here: [MouseEvent.clientX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

---

*This was originally a comment - moved into an answer as it qualifies as a valid answer to the original question.*

Comment: Can you copy the code in? In case the codepen goes away or something.

Comment: Apologies, was trying to avoid cluttering the answer with the HTML / CSS side of things. Moved.

Comment: Might be nice to reference some documentation as well for future visitors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Comment: Good suggestion

Comment: thanks everyone for the quick and precise responses, much appreciated!

Comment: and for future inquirers that have the same curiosity as me about where in the MDN docs referenced/linked above mentioning/confirming this answer, if you scroll to bottom, you'll see "See also:" [Coordinate Systems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSSOM_view/Coordinate_systems) . navigate there and you should be able to read about how coordinates are in pixels.